# Swift3 : Delegate function is not running

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates, protocols

I'm building an app where I start at a TableViewController and when I click on a cell it will go to another viewcontroller and run a function that I created in the new viewcontroller. I'm currently using protocols and delegate but even after following along tutorials and guides I find online I am still not able to get the function to run.

Here's my tableview controller code. I included the code that I thought relevant.

```
class interestPTableViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        var ipSearchDelegate: IPSearch?

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {       
                ipSearchDelegate?.ipZoom()
        }
}
```

Heres my other viewcontroller code. I cannot get it to print "hello"

```
protocol IPSearch: class{
      func ipZoom()
}

class searchMapViewController: BaseViewController{
      override func viewDidLoad(){
            let ipip = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "interestP") as! interestPTableViewController
            ipip.ipSearchDelegate = self
      }
}
extension searchMapViewController: IPSearch {
      func ipZoom(){
           print("hello")
      }
}
```

Any help will be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you put a breakpoint and tested what's going on?

Comment: Hmm not really sure how to exactly see what's going on. but my delegate is nil when I checked

Comment: This looks a little backwards... In general, use a Delegate pattern so that a loaded / displayed class can communicate *back* to the class that loaded it. Here is *looks* like you are trying to "call a delegate func in a class you just loaded"?

Comment: @DonMag What I'm essentially trying to do is when I click on a cell I want it to go to my viewcontroller which contains a map where it then zooms into the region by loading data that is given through the cell. But the map by itself works perfectly fine without having data loaded into it. I only want it to zoom when i navigate it through my tableview cells. if this make sense.

Comment: @JackieXY - are both your TableView and the view from your MapViewController visible on the screen at the same time? Like your map is showing on top, and you have a table below it to select from?

Comment: @DonMag no the tableview is in another viewcontroller. It is not showing at the same

Comment: @JackieXY - one more question, and then I'll see if I can give you a helpful answer... What is `BaseViewController`?

Comment: @DonMag BaseViewController is another view that handles my hamburger menu

Comment: Oh wait... are you showing the Map, then tapping somewhere on the map (or on a button) shows the Table? And then tapping on a row on the table should take you back to the map, with the "table selection" zoomed?

Comment: @DonMag Yes thats what i'm trying to do. But the table and map do not show together. I would have to go to my hamburger menu to navigate to the table when viewing my map. It doesn't hover over.

Comment: @JackieXY - how is your Hamburger Menu showing the Table View? Via a segue?

Comment: @DonMag no its through appending the viewcontroller. Im using these lines. 
            var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
            vcArray!.removeLast()
            vcArray!.append(destViewController)
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray!, animated: true)

Comment: @JackieXY - hmmm... well, the more "conventional" way would be to "push" the table view controller onto the stack, and then "pop" it back off after making a selection. That's what you commonly see the "slide-in-from-the-right / slide-back-out-to-the-right" ... I posted an answer that fits that process. The problem with your current approach is that your MapVC will be ***removed*** from the hierarchy, and won't be around for any delegate calls.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the answers. Will try out your process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your task is done in the "conventional" Protocol / Delegate pattern.

This is the "map view" controller...

```
//
//  SearchMapViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

protocol IPSearch: class{
    func ipZoom()
}

extension SearchMapViewController: IPSearch {
    func ipZoom(){
        print("hello")
    }
}

class SearchMapViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        // assuming another button (hamburger menu?) is triggering a segue
        // to the "table view" controller, this is where you
        // assign the delegate

        if let vc = segue.destination as? InterestPViewController {
            vc.delegate = self
        }

    }

}
```

This is the View with a Table of rows to select from...

```
//
//  InterestPViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class InterestPViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var delegate: IPSearch?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basicCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // just print so we know we've tapped a row
        print("row selected", indexPath.row)

        // call a func in the "map view" - likely, ipZoom() will be changed to
        // something along the lines of ipZoom(selectedRow: indexPath.row)
        delegate?.ipZoom()

        // returning to the "map view"

        // either
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        // or
        //presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way, you should keep instance of your VC:

```
    class searchMapViewController: BaseViewController{
      var ipip: interestPTableViewController! // <- This is important part

      override func viewDidLoad(){
            ipip = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "interestP") as! interestPTableViewController
            ipip.ipSearchDelegate = self
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but unfortunately this did not fix the problem. Is there any other suggestions that you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your SearchMapViewController's viewDidLoad is instantiating a new InterestPTableViewController and setting its delegate and then discarding it. That newly created view controller will be deallocated as soon as your viewDidLoad exits. The time to set the delegate is in prepareForSegue

.

Comment: Where would I set the prepareForSegue? Sorry I'm new to C language and swift in general

Comment: How do you trigger the second view controller when you tap a cell?

Comment: correction: I'm appending the viewcontroller on when the cell is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Make your first VC conform to your protocol

```
 class interestPTableViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, IPSearch {

        var ipSearchDelegate: IPSearch?

        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {       
                ipSearchDelegate?.ipZoom()
        }
}
```